# How can I represent Dim order(4) As Int16 in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How can I use `Dim order(4) As Int16` which I have declared in public class of VB in C# format?

```
where, 
order(0)=0;
order(1)=0;
order(2)=0;
order(3)=0;
```

Comment: That are default values, just initialize the array with the right size and you are finished

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That are default values, just initialize the array with the right size and you are finished.

Note that you want a length of 4 but

```
Dim order(4) As Int16
```

Initializes an array with the length 5. So you want this in VB.NET:

```
Dim order(3) As Int16
```

and this in C# (note that it's 4 here for the length 4):

```
short[] order = new short[4];
```

which is an alias for:

```
System.Int16[] order = new System.Int16[4];
```

Comment: " `Dim order(4) As Int16` ... Initializes an array with the length 5" - 100% correct, but wow: VB you have some quirks!

Comment: @MarcGravell: what quirks?

Comment: @TimSchmelter that non-intuitive array length off-by-one. I'm totally fine with questions over whether the index should be 0-based or 1-based, but the *length*?

Comment: @MarcGravell: true, i guess reason is VB6 compatibility

Answer (score 2):

It's an array, in c# it looks like this (with initializer):

```
var i = new short[] {0,0,0,0};
```

Comment: `int` is **not** `Int16`

Comment: @MarcGravell yep, thnx

Answer (score 1):

That looks like simply:

```
short[] order = new short[4];
```

You *could* also explicitly specify the defaults, but 0 is implicit *anyway* and it is cheaper *not* to do this, but:

```
short[] order = new short[] {0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Note that `short` is an alias for `System.Int16`. If this is a *local variable* (as opposed to a *field*), you can also simplify it further using `var`:

```
var order = new short[4];
```